# Project index array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these documents:

```
db.users.findOne({},{_id:0, Sigle:1});
{ "Sigle" : [ "RIPGD", "EDRFR" ]}
```

How can I make a request, to return this result

```
{ "Sigle" : "RIPGD"}
or this 
{ "Sigle" : "EDRFR"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) operator and if you don't need `_id` you can explicitly exclude it from results using `$project`:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Sigle: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$Sigle", 0 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: this request does not work !!!!

db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Sigle: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$Sigle", 0 ] }
        }
    }
])